# jquery open image in new window

Tags: jquery, html, variables, click

I have the following html:

```
<li><a href="#" filename="prettygirls_1"><img src="large/prettygirls_1.jpg" alt="Pretty Girls Doing Horrid Things" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" filename="prettygirls_2"><img src="large/prettygirls_2.jpg" alt="Pretty Girls Doing Horrid Things" /></a></li>
```

I am trying to write some jquery that will pass the filename property into a variable and then open a large version of the source file in a new window.

My jquery looks like this (I know this is incorrect):

```
$('div#slider ul li a').click(function() {
    var img_to_load = $(this).attr('filename');
    filePath = 'large/'; 
    $('<a href=" ' + filePath + img_to_load + '.jpg' + 'target="_blank"' + '</a>').html();
    //alert (img_to_load);
});
```

How do I construct this?

All the code is actually available here: http://dev.jessicaharby.com/work/tempindex.cfm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**JS:**

```
window.open(filePath + img_to_load + '.jpg', '', 'width=640,height=480');
```

Change the width and height to suit, or if you cannot specify an exact width and height, just use

```
window.open(filePath + img_to_load + '.jpg');
```

See [window.open - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Because it is opened on the `click` event, it won't be blocked by pop-up blockers, as long as the URL being opened is in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    // prevents the default action of the link's click-event ('e'), above
    e.preventDefault();
    // finds the 'img' element within the 'a', using 'find()`
    // and converts that, using '[0]' to a plain DOM node
    // and retrieves the full, absolute, 'src' from that element
    var img_to_load = $(this).find('img')[0].src,
        imgWindow = window.open(img_to_load, 'imgWindow');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yUdwt/).

The above will open any subsequently clicked images into the same window (reloading the opened-window with the new image element), as it will first see if there's a window open with the same name (in this case `'imgWindow'`, the second parameter in the `window.open()` function) and, if it exists, re-use it. Otherwise it'll open a window with that name.

If you want images to open in their own window every time, simply omit that parameter and simply use:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img_to_load = $(this).find('img')[0].src,
        imgWindow = window.open(img_to_load);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yUdwt/1/).

References:

- `event.preventDefault()` ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)), ([plain JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aevent.preventDefault)).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

Answer (score 0):

Now, solution for above query has been provided by codebins. So, try it on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpb5

```
$(function() {
    $('div#slider ul li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var imageWin;
        var imageUrl = $.trim($(this).attr('filename')),
            imageWin = window.open(imageUrl);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery demo</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(event) {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
});
</script>
<input type=button name="btn" id="btn">
</body>
</html>
```